# Just made a new android application project when i try and run the simple hello world it has an error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
Path for project must have only one segment

I only just got through a previous problem to straight away come to the next one , also when i try and created AVD , when i press the button "okay" , it does nothing , the box does not even close , any help ? cheers ,

Comment: Describe your problem more precisely, what you press okay on ?

Comment: the okay button is a separate problem , if i go on android device manager , then on device definitions , if i select one for example the nexus 10 , i then click on create AVD button on the right side , a box comes up asking for some details like target etc. I fill it in and when i press the "ok" button , nothing happens, the window does not even close to give me an error or anything , it just stays , its like the button does not work , but it does press in when i hover my cursor over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the probelm:

Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings: 1. select "Launching New_configuration" 2. Delete 3. OK

Comment: Additionaly click Run->Run Configuration, then try giving your project a name, if a name exists just rename it.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it has worked and i can now use my phone as to test the app , cheers

Comment: Sorry how do i do this ? Cheers

Comment: click on the tick near the answer :)

Comment: Ok yeah done that just realised haha , Don't suppose you have time for one more quick question while your here?

Comment: yea thats fine, what's the question ?

Comment: Well i am new to java , so the code itself is still a bit unknown , i know a bit of c++. So anyway on the Main Activity.java file that has been created with my new android application project , there is a bunch of code already there by default , this to be precise , my question is , could i just delete most of it to start a more fresh slate and still have the basic hello world program work ? or should i leave it how it is , if so , where would i enter new code ?/ cheers in advance if you can help me

Comment: Ok the code is too long for this box lol , but it seems to be declaring a lot of boolean

Answer (score 0):

Ok Beefydeadeye,  The Code that is in the activity you start with is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //put code between here 

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

It may look a little differnt for you,
This code defines the layout (Gui for the Activty) and the menu xml, if you create another activty in the project it will not start you with this code.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept answers on users posts if they answer your question and it resolves your problem.

Comment: i will show you all the code that is coming up for me

Comment: package com.example.attempt2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

Comment: Actually have you got facebook ? If you are willing that is i understand if not , just because i can post a screenshot to better show what i am talking about. Up to you though i understand if not

Comment: Yea i got fb, but it would be better to email me.

Comment: oh you selected a navigation type ect.. i usually select blank activity.

Comment: just email me ill take a look but i have too go :) my email on my profile page (plugin117@gmail.com), i promise i will reply lol

Comment: Cheers dude i have to go soon aswell as is 1 am for me haha  , cheers for all the help i will email you within a day or so

Comment: Yea no problem, if you ever need help, i'm only an email away :))